# Sending POST request from Angular 8 on localhost to server API

Tags: php, angular, api, post

I'm learning Angular 8 and now trying to send a post request from localhost to the api on shared hosting (tried on localhost before the server). I had the issue of origin source and fixed by installing Moesif Orign & CORS Changer extension for chrome. I have this code now

```
    onCreatePost(userData: { username: string; email: string, password: string, school: string }) {
    console.log(userData);
    this.http.post('http://example.net/insert.php', userData).subscribe( (response) => {
      console.log(response);
    });
  }
```

Here's the userData log

```
{username: "test name", email: "user@mail.com", password: "123456", school: "test school"}
```

I try to save the post data first before handling it

```
$postData = $_POST;
$q = $db->prepare("insert into post (data) value ('$postData')");
$q->execute();
$result['message'] = "test message";
echo json_encode($result);
```

but I get `Array` as a result in the field. I changed it too `json_encode($_POST)` but I get `[]` in the field. I can't find the data sent in the post request why is that?

Comment: Fixing a CORS issue by downloading an extension is far from a solution. Do you expect all of your user to download the extension aswell ? You should try to fix the issue rather than using developpement tool to go around them.

Comment: Also, you code is vulnerable to [sql injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)  you should always bind your paramters when using SQL statement.

Comment: can you please share Array data which you are getting ?

Comment: @Nicolas it's just to solve the connection from localhost while developing and testing and I know there's no security I'm just testing send data from Angular to PHP while learning

Comment: I don't think your SQL is correct. First, you have a typo where `value` should be `values`: `insert into post (data) values ('$postData')`, but `$postData` should be an object and you're treating is as a string. Have you logged what you are receiving in `$_POST` to make sure you are getting the correct info from your post? That should be your first step before you move on to worrying about how you are using that data.

Comment: _“but I get Array as a result in the field”_ - of course you do, because `$postData` is an array, but you are forcing it into a string context here - which in PHP, always results in the word “Array”. Your SQL query makes no sense to begin with, if you want to insert values into _multiple_ columns here.

Comment: See this tutorial https://www.techiediaries.com/php-angular/